# cantact form php file doesn't work(Jquery Magical contact form - tutsgeek)

Tags: php, forms, sendmail, contact-form

i have a form that work with jquery this form is :

download link for this is

http://www.4shared.com/rar/qkIP2Ulb/magical-contact-form.html

```
<form class="fcf-contact-form" action="mail.php" method="post">

     <div class="right">

         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input">

         <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input">

         <div class="left">           
            <textarea name="message" cols="0" rows="5" class="textarea"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send message !" class="submit"/>
         </div>

     </div>


</form>
```

and mail.php file code is that code :

```
<?php
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $phone = $_POST['message'];
   $formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n email: $email \n message: $message";
   $recipient = "milad.esmailzade@yahoo.com";
   $subject = "Contact Form";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
   echo "<a href='your page link here.php' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'></a>";
?>
```

i upload this contact form on the host and when i click send i dont recieve email from this form !
what is the problem ?

Comment: if ($phone == $_POST['message']) what does $message =?

Comment: What's the operating system of your Host?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or is it dying with Error!?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask your hosting technical support why the PHP mail function does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting SMTP and user parameters, like this:

```
ini_set("SMTP","mail.mydomain.com" ); // or the IP
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'Me@mydomain.com'); // Account used to deliver the messages.
```

Comment: download link for this :
http://www.4shared.com/rar/qkIP2Ulb/magical-contact-form.html

Comment: what can i use SMTP on mail.php file ?

Comment: If you are not sure what is the SMTP server, ask your ISP for help on that matter. Nevertheless, it is usually the one in the example. Replace mydomain.com with the name of your site's domain.